# converting java Date to day

Tags: java

I am working on a project where I have created 2 variables `startdate`,`enddate` of type `Date` in java.
As you know Date in Java includes both date and time.
But while querying I only need the date (specifically day) part of the startdate variable.
I tried `startdate.getday()` but it says it's deprecated and I should use `Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` instead.
But I don't know how to use this, tried googling everywhere, the solution is to get the current date.

I want to do something if startdate contains (30/01/1988 02:30:54) so that I get 30/01/1988 or if possible 30 and 01 and 1988 separately in string/int variables.

Comment: Get the current date in what time zone? Note that using Joda Time (http://joda-time.sf.net) is normally a *much* better idea... How much of the `Calendar` documentation have you read? (That should explain the "how to use this")

Comment: Do you need an actual java.util.Date stripped off all the higher resolution parts (time) or can it be a String?  If you tell us the class of the expected result, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTime(startdate);
 cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: thanks u both Duncan Jones and shyam int day=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);   :D

Comment: Be careful here with implicit time zone.

Answer (score 1):

The `java.util.Date` class is part of the old data-time classes that are poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them.

Instead use the java.time classes.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) team also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## `Instant`

First step is to get out of the old classes and into the new. For conversion, new methods have been added to the old classes. The `java.util.Date` class now offers `toInstant`. An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution as fine as nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant();
```

## Time Zone

Determining a date requires a time zone. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by time zone. A few minutes after midnight in Paris is still “yesterday” in Montréal.

The `ZoneId` class represents a time zone. Notice that we never use the 3-4 letter abbreviations as commonly seen in mainstream media such as `EST` or `IST`. These are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!). Instead use [proper time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) defined in the tz database in format `continent/region`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zoneId );
```

Interrogate the `ZonedDateTime` for the parts you need.

```
int year = zdt.getYear();
int month = zdt.getMonthValue(); // Or handy Month enum…  zdt.getMonth();
int dayOfMonth = zdt.getDayOfMonth();
```

## `LocalDate`

If you are doing extensive work where you decidedly want to ignore time-of-day and time zone, use the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

```
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate();
```